# Reading input from a file in Java

Tags: java

I am having the following file have 3 columns , i want read the following file and store them `ArrayList` , how to read it using `Scanner` or `Buffer reader` ?

For Example.

```
ArrayList<Integert>[][] M = new ArrayList[size][size]

M[1][859].add(1806476)
M[3][800].add(2131700)
M[3][800].add(2734107).. so one

A   B      C
1   859 [1806476]
3   800 "[2131700, 2734107, 2877209, 2877209]"
4   815 [2883211]
7   815 "[2429412, 2886810, 2886804]"
7   362 [2909301]
7   806 [89573]
7   853 [2182646]
8   800 "[2910937, 2836340, 2884417]"
```

Comment: This has been said multiple times, but I'll say it again. "**Arrays and Generics don't mix well**" Try using a `List<List<Integer>>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to store it in `arrayList`. You can use below approach

create a class of fields

```
class Multi {
    int a, b, c;
}

public void addrecords(int i, int j, int k) {
    Multi multi = new Multi();
    Multi.a = i;
    Multi.b = j;
    Multi.c = k;
    records.add(Multi);
}


List<Multi> records;
//code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void parseInput(Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, List<Integer>> data, String line) {
    String[] tmp = line.split(" ");
    String result = line.substring(tmp[0].length() + tmp[1].length() + 2);
    result = result.replaceAll("\"", "");
    result = result.replace(",", "");
    result = result.replace("[", "");
    result = result.replace("]", "");

    List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String a: result.split(" "))
        t.add(Integer.parseInt(a));

    data.put(new Pair<>(Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]), Integer.parseInt(tmp[1])), t);
}


    BufferedReader reader = null;
    FileReader fileReader = null;

    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader("in.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line;
        Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, List<Integer>> data = new HashMap<>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            parseInput(data, line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
            if (fileReader != null)
                fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

plus add try/catch block when u parse String to Integer